# scala syntax to match on multiple case class types without decomposing the case class

Tags: scala, syntax, pattern-matching, case-class

I have a sealed trait with various case class implementations. I want to pattern match on multiple classes at once for the same match expression. I can't seem to do it without decomposing the case classes and "|" between them

currently looks like:

```
sealed trait MyTrait {
  val param1: String
  ...
  val param100: String
}

case class FirstCase(param1: String ...... param100: String) extends MyTrait
...
case class NthCase(param1: String ..... param100: String) extends MyTrait
```

another place in code:

```
def myFunction(something: MyTrait) = {
   ...
   val matchedThing = something match {
      // this doesn't work with "|" character
      case thing: FirstCase | SecondCase => thing.param1
      ...
      case thing: XthCase | JthCase => thing.param10
   }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's go there step by step:

1. The `|` operator, in the context of pattern matching, allows you to define alternative *patterns*, in the following form:

   ```
   pattern1 | pattern2
   ```
2. If you want to define a pattern that matches a type, the pattern must be provided in the following form:

   ```
   binding: Type
   ```
3. Providing a choice between two different types should then be provided in the following form:

   ```
   binding1: Type1 | binding2: Type2
   ```
4. To bind a single name to the two alternative bindings you can discard the name of the individual bindings (using the `_` wildcard) and bind the name of the overall pattern to another binding using the `@` operator, as expressed in the following example:

   ```
   binding @ (_ : Type1 | _ : Type2)
   ```

The following is an example:

```
sealed trait Trait {
  def a: String
  def b: String
}

final case class C1(a: String, b: String) extends Trait
final case class C2(a: String, b: String) extends Trait
final case class C3(a: String, b: String) extends Trait

object Trait {
  def f(t: Trait): String =
   t match {
    case x @ (_ : C1 | _ : C2) => x.a // the line you are probably interested in
    case y: C3 => y.b
  }
}
```

Here is some sample output on invoking `f`:

```
scala> Trait.f(C1("hello", "world"))
res0: String = hello

scala> Trait.f(C2("hello", "world"))
res1: String = hello

scala> Trait.f(C3("hello", "world"))
res2: String = world
```

You can play around with the presented examples [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/2E8frVF4SBq5MDChjOmYwA).

Comment: Shame this is an answer to a duplicated question - this answer is better than the one in the first question asked. Great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pT4euWh6TFukqiuPr4T6GA:

```
sealed trait Sup {
  def a: String
  def i: Int
}

case class First(a: String, i: Int, d: Double) extends Sup

case class Second(a: String, i: Int, x: Seq[Double]) extends Sup

case class Third(a: String, i: Int, c: Char) extends Sup

val sups = Seq(First("s", 1, 1.0), Second("s", 4, Seq(1.1)), Third("s", 4, 'f'))

sups.foreach {
  case _: First | _: Second => println("ffff")
  case _                    => println("ggg")
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works if you replace the "_" with a parameter "m" (for both places)

Comment: I used the `_` as a _don't care_ just in order to show how to toggle on the types. If you do _care_ and want to access the attributes or methods of the actual instance @stefanobaghino answer is more instructive concerning that